# Codeigniter Smiley Helper not displaying out the symbols which represents the gif images

Tags: codeigniter

Hey guys am trying to display smilies  in my chatroom using codeigniter smiley  helper function but if I click on the  smiley nothing is showing up, am just getting a javascript error saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: insert_smiley is not defined` in the console

Here is my controller

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('smiley');
    $this->load->library('table');
     }
    public function index(){

        //If the user is logged in then load the chat room
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){


        //Add the smileys in the chat room!
        $image_array = get_clickable_smileys(base_url()."img/smileys/", 'msg_input');
        //Generate the a table where the smiley faces will be displayed!
        $col_array = $this->table->make_columns($image_array,8);
        $data['display_smileys'] = $this->table->generate($col_array);

        $data['main_contents'] = 'room_view';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
        }else{
            //if the user is not logged display login form to the his/her username!
         $data['main_contents'] = 'site_home';
         $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
         }
      }
```

And this is my view

```
<div class="container">
<?php echo $display_smileys; ?>
   </div>
  <li class="divider"></li>
   <li><a href="#">Smiley Faces</a></li>
  </ul>
</span>
<input type="text"  id="msg_input"  name="msg_input" class="form-control input-lg" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)" placeholder="Type here your message">
<span class="input-group-btn"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="send_msg">Send</a></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Thank you for the support

Comment: echo it at the very bottom of your HTML

Comment: dont you need this as well? `<?php echo smiley_js(); ?>`

Comment: Thank you CodeGodie, it works fine right now, thank you very much

Comment: Hey CodeGodie, it is working but the symbols are not changing to into icons

Comment: No problem. I provided my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to echo `smiley_js()` in order for that to work:

```
<?php echo smiley_js(); ?>
```

Comment: so the symbols are not changing? did you download the images folder: https://ellislab.com/asset/ci_download_files/smileys.zip?

Comment: Yes I downloaded the folder,  I can see the  images in the browser and they are all clickable but when it reaches the time of displaying symbols such as  >:-(  it can't change to normal smiley